# How do I remove json data from a list and then flatten into columns in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have this json data from Amazon..

```
[{'sellingProgramName': 'AMAZON_PRIME_NOW', 'salesMetricsByProgram': []},
 {'sellingProgramName': 'AMAZON_FRESH', 'salesMetricsByProgram': []},
 {'sellingProgramName': 'AMAZON_RETAIL',
  'salesMetricsByProgram': [{'asin': 'B001U81442',
    'salesMetricsByAsin': [{'reportingDate': '2021-01-20',
      'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99,
        'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 5.25, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedUnits': 1,
       'customerReturns': 0,
       'freeReplacements': 0,
       'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedUnits': 1,
       'preOrderedUnits': 0,
       'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': 84,
       'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83,
       'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0,
       'lostBuyBox': 0.0,
       'glanceViews': 3,
       'conversionRate': 0.3333}},
     {'reportingDate': '2021-01-21',
      'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0,
        'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedUnits': 0,
       'customerReturns': 0,
       'freeReplacements': 0,
       'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedUnits': 0,
       'preOrderedUnits': 0,
       'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None,
       'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83,
       'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0,
       'lostBuyBox': 0.0,
       'glanceViews': 0,
       'conversionRate': 0.0}}]},
   {'asin': 'B003SVYRNE',
    'salesMetricsByAsin': [{'reportingDate': '2021-06-28',
      'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0,
        'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedUnits': 0,
       'customerReturns': 1,
       'freeReplacements': 0,
       'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedUnits': 0,
       'preOrderedUnits': 0,
       'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None,
       'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None,
       'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0,
       'lostBuyBox': 0.0,
       'glanceViews': 0,
       'conversionRate': 0.0}},
     {'reportingDate': '2021-06-29',
      'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0,
        'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'shippedUnits': 0,
       'customerReturns': 0,
       'freeReplacements': 0,
       'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'},
       'orderedUnits': 0,
       'preOrderedUnits': 0,
       'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None,
       'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None,
       'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0,
       'lostBuyBox': 0.0,
       'glanceViews': 0,
       'conversionRate': 0.0}}]},
```

I've used json_normalize to get the data into this dataframe using this code

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=j,record_path=['salesMetricsByProgram'],errors='ignore')
```

and I get this dataframe

```
    asin        salesMetricsByAsin                                                      
0   B001U81442  [{'reportingDate': '2021-01-20', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 5.25, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 1, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 9.99, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 1, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': 84, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 3, 'conversionRate': 0.3333}}, {'reportingDate': '2021-01-21', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': 83, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}]    AMAZON_RETAIL
1   B003SVYRNE  [{'reportingDate': '2021-06-28', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 1, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}, {'reportingDate': '2021-06-29', 'salesMetricsByDate': {'shippedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedCOGS': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'shippedUnits': 0, 'customerReturns': 0, 'freeReplacements': 0, 'preOrderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedRevenue': {'amount': 0.0, 'currencyCode': 'USD'}, 'orderedUnits': 0, 'preOrderedUnits': 0, 'shippedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'orderedSubcategorySalesRank': None, 'replenishableOutOfStock': 0.0, 'lostBuyBox': 0.0, 'glanceViews': 0, 'conversionRate': 0.0}}]    AMAZON_RE
```

I'm trying to normalize the SalesMetricsByAsin column by using this code, while keeping the `asin` column

```
df['salesMetricsByAsin'] = pd.json_normalize(df['salesMetricsByAsin'],errors = 'ignore')
```

and I get this error

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`

It looks like the json data is nested in a list.  How do I remove the data from the list  so I can flatten the data into separate columns, while keeping the `asin` column?

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `json_normalize` on a list of dictionaries or with at least one dictionary. You could try this:

```
df['salesMetricsByAsin'] = [pd.json_normalize(d, errors='ignore') for d in df['salesMetricsByAsin']]
```

But the output would be a list too, but a list of JSON data. So you'd have to think wether you are going to consume this column as a list or spread it.

Comment: I would love to flatten the data in the salesMetricsByAsin into separate columns.  How would I do that from the list I now have?

Comment: @timc to spread the data into additional columns I would suggest you process the column independently and then check the depth of the resulting list. I don't know if in the data you might find lists with one, two or more dictionaries or if the column is consistent and can be split into two other columns (looking at the reporting dates in the dictionary)